# outer join on junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using mssql

How do I do a outer join on three tables, one of which is a junction table?

There can be nulls in the menu or product tables and I need these included in the result.

```
SELECT *
from [web].[dbo].[tblMenus]
left outer JOIN [web].[dbo].[tblProductsRelMenus] 
on [tblMenus].Id  = [tblProductsRelMenus].MenuId
left outer JOIN [web].[dbo].[tblProducts] 
on [tblProductsRelMenus].ProductId = [tblProducts].ProductId
```

This doesn't give menu nulls, and if I change the second left to a right, I loose the product nulls...

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: you are looking for a full outer join.

Comment: [probably] [a] [database] [that] [needs] [a] [lot] [of] [angle] [brackets] [.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a [full outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx)

```
SELECT *
from [web].[dbo].[tblMenus]
full outer JOIN [web].[dbo].[tblProductsRelMenus] 
on [tblMenus].Id  = [tblProductsRelMenus].MenuId
full outer JOIN [web].[dbo].[tblProducts] 
on [tblProductsRelMenus].ProductId = [tblProducts].ProductId
```

Comment: Note: first full outer join is not mandatory. First one may be a left outer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
        [web].[dbo].[tblMenus]
    LEFT JOIN
            [web].[dbo].[tblProductsRelMenus] 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
            [web].[dbo].[tblProducts] 
          ON [tblProductsRelMenus].ProductId = [tblProducts].ProductId
      ON [tblMenus].Id  = [tblProductsRelMenus].MenuId
```